# Is it a bad practice to use `require` inside a constructor in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, require

I am building a node app where a certain wordlist is required. The wordlist is in a JSON file that looks something like this:

```js
 { 
   "en":["foo", "bar"],
   "gr": ["foo", "bar"]
 }
```

Each key inside of the JSON file represents a different language.

The user has to pick a language when they create their object. So I am thinking of importing the JSON file inside of the constructor like this:

```js
const list = require('./config/lang.json')[lang]
```

Where lang is a parameter passed to the constructor.

Is this bad practice?

I've heard people say that you should always use `require` in the beginning of your code. Should I just require the whole thing in the beginning of my code `const list = require('./config/lang.json')` and then simply extract only the required language `const wordlist = list[lang]`inside the constructor?

Comment: I would require it once and use the variable once I have the parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though the code works the same, and `require` calls are cached. In your case there is no need for that extra function call on every new instance, so it will be faster (not that it matters in this case) to do the following:

```
const langs = require('./config/lang.json');

class MyClass {
    constructor(lang) {
        const list = langs[lang];
    }
}
```

Another thing to notice, is that `require` is synchronous, so if your JSON is specially large, the first time you instanciate `MyClass` the event loop will be blocked. Using it at the very beginning it will probably have loaded before the server (or whatever you're doing) has started, so there would be no issue in the `require` taking some time.

So, yes, in my opinion, `require` calls should be at the top, unless you know what you're doing, or you're loading a dynamic dependency.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a bad practice?

Not really, `require` has a cache so it doesn't matter a lot.

> I've heard people say that you should always use require in the beginning of your code.

Yes, that's a good practice so that one can easily spot the dependencies.

> Should I just require the whole thing in the beginning of my code `const list = require('./config/lang.json')` and then simply extract only the required language `const wordlist = list[lang]` inside of the constructor?

Yes, I would do that. I'd only put `require` inside the constructor if it was a dynamic dependency, like `const wordlist = require(`./config/lang/${lang}.json`)`.